# Comparison operator is uncertain

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

i've overloaded some comparison operators in my Student class.
When i try to use them, the result is uncertain:

```
class Student {
public:
    int ID;
    int grade;
    int teamID;
    int power;
    Student(int id,int grade, int power): ID(id),
        grade(grade),teamID(-1),power(power){};
    ~Student() {};
bool operator==(Student* right) {
    return this->ID == right->ID;
}
bool operator<(Student* right) {
    return this->ID < right->ID;
}

bool operator>(Student* right) {
    return this->ID > right->ID;
}


};
```

And this is where the weird things happen:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Student* s1 = new Student(i + 1, i + 1, i + 1);
        Student* s2 = new Student(i + 2, i + 1, i + 1);
        cout << (s1 < s2);  
    }
```

The result is always some permutation of zeros and ones, nothing stable.
I have no idea why this might happen. Can anyone help me? The reason why i'm using pointers is that i use a pointer to Student as a type T for another template class.

Comment: You're just comparing pointers. For your operators two be called, one of the students needs to not be a pointer.

Comment: Please see this for all our operator overloading needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: Thanks guys, it really helped :)